# apartment gem - not creating tables postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

Rails `5.x` , postgres , `apartment` gem

only below two tables created when `Apartment::Tenant.create('microsoft')` other 20 tables are not created, still in public schemas. `microsoft` schema created but not tables

[image]

Here is my `apartment.rb`

```
config.excluded_models = %w{ Account }
```

and tenant names

```
config.tenant_names = lambda { Account.pluck :domain }
```

use schemas

```
config.use_schemas = true
```

when I do rake `db:migrate` it is not creating anything on schema.rb whereas I created a new app with apartment. its generating another set of migration inside `schema.rb.`

eg: `create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql` format enabled `config/application.rb`

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

as mentioned in the apartment config,

*Apartment can be forced to use raw SQL dumps instead of schema.rb for creating new schemas.
Use this when you are using some extra features in PostgreSQL that can't be represented in
schema.rb, like materialized views etc. (only applies with use_schemas set to true).
(Note: this option doesn't use db/structure.sql, it creates SQL dump by executing pg_dump)*

```
config.use_sql = true
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `apartment.rb` file in the initializers.

Confirm that your new tenant is configured. If you have a static array you need to extend it.

```
config.tenant_names = ['tenant1', 'myothertenant', 'microsoft']
```

You can make it also dynamic by adding a lambda to the config:

```
config.tenant_names = lambda { some_tenant_loading_func }
```

Also check that you have set the pg specific option:

```
config.use_schemas = true
```

This option specifies whether to use PostgreSQL schemas or create a new database per tenant.